# Loading XML file from UNC Path not working propertly

Tags: c#, xml, unc

I want to load an XML file located on my server so I can get the value of the XML Element called "CheckInterval" and store it on a string called "NewIntervalSet".

I am loading the following XML file called "ConfigFile.xml".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Cart>
  <CartConfiguration>
     <CheckInterval>0.25</CheckInterval>
  </CartConfiguration>
</Cart>
```

The way that I am loading it is the following:

```
XElement xelement;
xelement = XElement.Load(Path.Combine("\\\\server\\public\\Engineering","ConfigFile.xml"));
```

The way that I'm storing the XML element "CheckInterval" into the string "NewIntervalSet" is the following:

```
string NewIntervalSet;
NewIntervalSet=xelement.Descendants("CartConfiguration")
     .Select(x => x.Element("CheckInterval").Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

When I place a breakpoint where the file is being loaded I can see that the file is loading correctly, so I know the path is right, but when it tries to select the XML element it skips this line of code and it returns a null value, therefore a null string on the "NewIntervalSet" variable. I have no idea why is doing this, when I use the same code but the path is on the local machine it works correct.

Comment: Try mapping the path as a drive and open from there.  In my experience, using UNC paths is asking for permission problems.

Comment: if that is the actual code it should return 0.25.Are you positive that the file has loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this problem by loading the XML file as an XDocument and not as an XElement. The new way that I'm loading the XML file is the following:

```
XDocument xDocument;
xDocument= XDocument.Load(Path.Combine("\\\\server\\public\\Engineering","ConfigFile.xml"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program may be running into a permissions issue. According to MSDN, [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298435%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) creates by calling [XmlReader.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k674bf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which in turn has the following to say

> A default XmlUrlResolver with no credentials is used to access any
>   external resources such as a document type definition (DTD), entities,
>   schemas, and so on. If the external resource is located on a network
>   resource that requires authentication, specify an XmlResolver with the
>   necessary credentials using the XmlReaderSettings.XmlResolver
>   property.

Since your XML document is located on a network path, it's using default/null credentials, causing it to get no read permissions and an empty document. Try opening the file as a stream so you can make a run where it reads out text, and then pipe that stream into a new XElement using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838544%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload. Alternatively, instantiate the XmlResolver yourself so you can set the credentials.